# TypeScript - Change property type in child, is it possible?

Tags: inheritance, typescript, overriding

I have a class `Manager`:

```
class Manager{
    /**
     * Elements that are managed by the manager.
     */
    private _elements: PIXI.DisplayObject[];
```

and a class `TextureManager` which extends the `Manager`:

```
export class TextureManager extends Game.Managers.Manager{
    private _elements: PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer[];
}
```

Just so you know, `PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer` extends `PIXI.DisplayObject`.

I believe that because it is the same type *(based on the same object: `PIXI.DisplayObject`)*, the type change should be possible. (at least it is in real OOP languages, like Java, *if I remember correctly*)

But I get this error message during the compilation. How should I do?

> TextureManager.ts(9,18): error TS2416: Class 'TextureManager' incorrectly extends base class 'Manager':
>   Types have separate declarations of a private property '_elements'.

**Solution:**

It may seem like a simple solution, but TS `1.3` has just been released like 3 days ago and add support for the -really wanted- `protected` attribute. And it seem to work with a `protected` attribute it does work fine to change the type, I just set `protected _elements: any;` on the `Manager` parent class and customize the type as I want in any child `protected _elements: Game.Core.Texture;`. Pretty cool.

I just get red everywhere since my IDE (WebStorm) hasn't released a support for TS 1.3, but by checking `Trigger watcher regardless of syntax error` in the `File watcher` I was able to make it work. Support coming soon: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14149

Comment: Which version of TypeScript do you use? In 1.3, released few days ago, there's `protected` keyword introduced and it would probably help here.

Comment: 1.3, installed it today. Didn't think about that. Gonna give a try.

Comment: It works, thanks. Lucky it has just been released.

Comment: I've added the solution, thanks or your help, appreciated!

Comment: You coud have add this as an answer so that everyone see the question has a solution (you mind if I do it?). And, besides, you don't have to use `any` type in your superclass, if `PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer` extends `PIXI.DisplayObject` then you can also use `PIXI.DisplayObject` there

Comment: The example was using pixi, but I use `any[]` now and override it in each child because I don't have a common parent class for every item actually. Please write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't override a private class member in TypeScript. Before the version 1.3, which was released a few days ago, there were only 2 accessibility modifiers in TS: `private` and `public`, so the only solution here would be to use `public`.

It changed in the version 1.3. While private members still cannot be overriden, TS 1.3 introduces the `protected` accessibility modifier. It still prevents the property from being accessed outside the class, however it allows members to be accessed in subclasses and, which is more relevant to the question, **allows overriding** (but type of property that overrides still has to be assignable to the overriden's one).

So in this case just use TypeScript 1.3, make `_elements` protected and give it a type that it's possible to be overriden.

Comment: I just found out that another solution is to use `generics<type>`, see the following: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx